# Java Web Service deployment error in Glassfish 4.0 server

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, glassfish, jax-ws

I am writing a simple java web service which has few methods which creates and access database using SQL libraries in java. When I tried to deploy it on Glassfish 4.0 I get Error as give below. Please help me in deploying I tried to catch all the exceptions in the methods in which I access database. 
My Web Service Code has methods like given below:

```
public boolean processOrder(int cust_id) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    try{
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        System.out.println("Connecting to Database...");
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(newDB_URL,USER,PASS);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        String sql = "DELETE FROM Orders WHERE cust_id ="+cust_id;
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        return true;
    }catch(SQLException se){
        se.printStackTrace(); }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace(); }
    return false;
}
```

The above given method is one such method there are few other methods they do some way or the other same task of accessing database. The error I am getting when I deploy on Glassfish is given below.

```
cannot Deploy FalseSecure
deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app  
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Servlet web service  endpoint '' failure. Please see server.log for more details.
```

I am using Eclipse IDE for doing this project. Please follow up the server.log given below.
Please find server.log file here in the cloud its too big to copy it here.
Link:https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62247131/server.log

Comment: Please update the question with the error message from `server.log`.

Comment: @unwichtich please see the question I have updated. Thanks in advance.